# Dropbox Paper API - video not showing when posting markdown

Tags: dropbox-api

I am able to create new paper documents using the Dropbbox Paper API, however when I post markdown - nothing I try is able to include video's in the post - instead I get just the text and a link to the video - no video showing.

I try sending the same markdown as is exported and it still does not work - for instance neither of these forms work:

```
# Test

[https://youtu.be/rhSg9X3q2gc](https://youtu.be/rhSg9X3q2gc)
https://youtu.be/rhSg9X3q2gc
```

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Paper-API-video-not-showing/m-p/320408#M18892 ]

The Dropbox Paper API doesn't offer the ability to programmatically embed media like that unfortunately. When uploading using [/2/paper/docs/create](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#paper-docs-create) or [/2/paper/docs/update](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#paper-docs-update) you'll just get the text, as mentioned. I'll pass this along as a feature request.